# Refreshing SQL view after adding a default constraint to one of its tables

Tags: sql, view, refresh

How exactly can I refresh the view after adding a default constraint to one of the tables that makes up the view? I tried to use the sp_refreshview stored procedure but that didn't actually update the view. Here is the code I wrote to update one of columns with a default value:

```
ALTER TABLE chosenTable
ADD CONSTRAINT defaultConstraint
DEFAULT '1' FOR selectedColumn
```

Here is the code I used to see whether or not the constraint is there before and after running the above code:

```
SELECT object_definition(default_object_id) AS definition
FROM sys.columns WHERE name = 'selectedColumn'
AND object_id = object_id('choseTable')
```

The previous statement can be used to see if the column of that name has been updated in the view as well. The problem is that the column has the constraint in the table itself, but the constraint is not added to the view. After trying the sp_refreshview and having no success, I'm stuck. I would appreciate any tips that don't outright involve dropping the view and recreating it. But if that is the only solution, is it simply a matter of using the DROP command and then making the view like normal?

After dropping the view, here is my attempt to recreate it. It doesn't allow me to recreate it:

```
CREATE VIEW newView
AS SELECT * FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table2
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table3
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table4
```

It says that the synax is incorrect and that 'CREATE VIEW' must be the only statement in the batch. Trying to run it says that all queries combined using a UNION must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists. However, I'm following the query format in the official documentation. What can I try to fix this?

Comment: Instead of "select *" it would pay to specify your columns. I suspect that in one table or another there is a different number of columns. It would be a good test to see if you can get it to run that way, in any case. If you do the select * from table1, select * from table2 separately do you get the same number of columns?

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks for your help. If you'd like to get your points, please post your comment as the answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of "select *" it would pay to specify your columns. I suspect that in one table or another there is a different number of columns.

A good test would be to do the select * from table1/table2 etc and just see what they are bringing back